# c# Change textboxwithfont height dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, textbox

I'm trying to get a `textbox` to change its height dynamically while maintainign a fixed `width`. Cuttently when the `text` is too long and goes too a second line the `textbox` does not `resize`.

The `textbox` is sized after all text has been added.

Below is what I'm currently using.

```
txtwfSupportNotes[i].Multiline = true;
txtwfSupportNotes[i].Text += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Notes"].ToString() 
+ "\r\n\r\n";
Size txtSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(txtwfSupportNotes[i]
.Text, txtwfSupportNotes[i].Font);
txtwfSupportNotes[i].Width = 355;
txtwfSupportNotes[i].Height = txtSize.Height+5;
txtwfSupportNotes[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

EDIT: Got a fix, see below.

```
Size txtSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(txtwfSupportNotes[i].Text, txtwfSupportNotes[i].Font, txtwfSupportNotes[i].ClientRectangle.Size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
txtwfSupportNotes[i].Height = txtSize.Height+5;
```

Comment: are you calling the above in the `TextChanged` event? Looks fine to me.

Comment: The text is only ever set once, and is set before any sizing is done, I'll edit the original post to show an example.

Comment: I take it you are updating this as part of a loop? You shouldn't have to set the width every time if it's supposed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a wpf or winforms application, if that is the case, don't set the height, (but use wrapping,) then your textbox should resize dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the FontChanged Event of the TextBox? Do it like this:

```
private void txtwfSupportNotes_FontChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size txtSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(txtwfSupportNotes.Text, txtwfSupportNotes.Font);
        txtwfSupportNotes.Height = txtSize.Height + 5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use MinHeight property, I think it should dynamically rezise your textbox :

```
txtwfSupportNotes[i].MinHeight = txtSize.Height+5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the "Locked" property = false on the text box control in the designer?